# People guesser program with JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn JavaScript, and so I'm doing this project to practice. I'm trying to figure out how the objects and all that work. Basically what I want, is a list of people, as objects, with certain properties assigned to each. Then it to ask a bunch of questions until it guesses the person you're thinking of. I've searched around, but can't really find exactly how to do this. This is what I have so far:

```
function person(name,age,eyecolor,gender,eyeglasses)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.eyecolor=eyecolor;
    this.gender=gender;
    this.eyeglasses=eyeglasses;
}

var Dad=new person("Dad",45,"blue","male",true);
var Mom=new person("Mom",48,"blue","female",false);
var Brother=new person("Brother",16,"blue","male",false);
var Sister=new person("Sister",15,"green","female",false);

function askQuestion (){

}

function begin(){
    askQuestion();
}
```

Now what I want is a way that I can, in the `askQuestion` function, select a question from a list based on what we know so far about the person. And then recalculate who of the people it could be, and then pick another question to ask, until we know who it is. Hopefully I've made this clear. How would I do that?

Comment: Try `prompt("What is their gender?")`, etc. and compare it to the genders of the people.

Comment: Ok, but I don't really know Javascript well enough. What is a prompt? And how do I compare it?

Comment: @eshellborn SO is not a code-writing service. As http://stackoverflow.com/faq says, SO is for questions about "a specific programming problem."

Comment: Interesting question, but it's probably a good idea here to do the algorithm part yourself on paper, if only to save a question from downvotes! This is good practise in itself: once you have designed the algorithm using natural language, you can then convert it to pseudo-code, and from there to a language-specific solution.

Comment: @halfer Ah, ok. Good idea, thanks! And ok, I see, I just was a bit stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit like the game "[Guess Who?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guess_Who%3F)" no? Alright so this is what you do:

First you create a constructor for a person. You got this right.

```
function Person(name, age, eyecolor, gender, eyeglasses) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyecolor = eyecolor;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.eyeglasses = eyeglasses;
}
```

Then you create list of possible people. A list means an array.

```
var people = [
    new Person("Dad", 45, "blue", "male", true),
    new Person("Mom", 48, "blue", "female", false),
    new Person("Brother", 16, "blue", "male", false),
    new Person("Sister", 15, "green", "female", false)
];
```

Then you keep asking questions to guess who the person is. To keep asking means to use a loop. We'll keep looping until there's only one person left in the list (the person we're looking for):

```
while (people.length > 1) askQuestion();
```

Next we define the `askQuestion` function. First we need to select what question to ask. So we make a list of questions. Again this is an array. We'll also store which property to test and the result for `true` and `false` conditions.

```
var questions = [
    ["eyecolor", "blue", "green", "Does the person have blue eyes?"],
    ["gender", "male", "female", "Is the person a male?"],
    ["eyeglasses", true, false, "Does the person wear eyeglasses?"]
];
```

These three questions are all you need to know to determine who the person is. Next we record which question is currently being asked (0, 1 or 2).

```
var question_no = 0;
```

Finally we ask the questions to determine who the person is:

```
function askQuestion() {
    var question = questions[question_no++];
    var answer = confirm(question[3]) ? question[1] : question[2];
    var predicate = question[0];

    people = people.filter(function (person) {
        return person[predicate] === answer;
    });
}
```

Here we ask the user a question, determine which answer he chose and use that information to filter the people who match the given description. Finally we end up with one person:

```
alert("The person you're thinking about is " + people[0].name + ".");
```

See the working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/9g6XU/

Comment: Now, quickly, let's just say that 'Dad' had brown eyes. What could we do for that? Would there be a quick way to change it so that would work?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it. It's shorter than Aadit's answer, and in my opinion, simpler and easier to understand.

Make a list of the people. Use an array literal:

```
var people = [Dad, Mom, Brother, Sister];
```

I like to structure my code, so I would put the questions in an object:

```
var questions = {
    "Are they male or female?" : 'gender',
    "What is their eye color?" : 'eyecolor',
    "Do they wear glasses?" : 'eyeglasses'
};
```

This could be expanded with as many properties as you want.

Then:

```
for (question in questions) { //This is how you loop through an object
    var property = questions[question]; //This gets the second part of the object property, e.g. 'gender'
    var answer = prompt(question);

    //filter is an array method that removes items from the array when the function returns false.
    //Object properties can be referenced with square brackets rather than periods. This means that it can work when the property name (such as 'gender') is saved as a string.

    people = people.filter(function(person) { return person[property] == answer });

    if (people.length == 1) {
        alert("The person you are thinking of is " + people[0].name);
        break;
    }
    if (people.length == 0) {
        alert("There are no more people in the list :(");
        break;
    }
}
```

And I, too, made you a fiddle.[Here it is.](http://jsfiddle.net/aGb4W/1/)